# Distance in a Riemannian Product

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Is it true in general that $d((x,y),(x',y'))^2 = d_M(x,x')^2+d_N(y,y')^2$ in a Riemannian Product $M\times N$?

I read (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084841) that this holds if in $M$ geodesics are unique. But what is then wrong with this argument: Let $E(\gamma)=\int_0^1|\dot{\gamma}|^2dt$ be the energy of the curve $\gamma: [0,1]\to M$ in a smooth manifold $M$. In a Riemannian product manifold $M\times N$ every curve has the form $\gamma = (\gamma_1,\gamma_2)$ with energy $E((\gamma_1,\gamma_2)) = E(\gamma_1)+E(\gamma_2)$. Then
$$d((x,y),(x',y'))^2 = \inf E((\gamma_1,\gamma_2)) = \inf E(\gamma_1) + \inf E(\gamma_2) = d_M(x,x')^2 + d_N(y,y')^2$$ where the infima are taken over all piecewise differentiable curves in $M\times N$ and $M$ respectively $N$.

Comment: why is $\inf E((\gamma_1,\gamma_2))= \inf E(\gamma_1) + \inf E(\gamma_2)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Riemannian distance function on a product manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491826/riemannian-distance-function-on-a-product-manifold)

Comment: @Thomas because we can vary $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ separately

Comment: @ArcticChar not fully. Is my energy approach correct? It seems a little easier maybe.

Comment: The energy equals the length only when the curves are parametrized proportional to arc length. That $\gamma = (\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$ is parametrized proportional to arc length does not mean that $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are.

Comment: @ArcticChar yes but the infimum of the energy over all curves should be $d(x,y)^2$? I mean the distance is the infimum over all lengths and I can reparametrize the curve, because I look at all curves?

Comment: My advice is to write out the proof in more detail. You’ll be able to see more clearly whether your proof is right or not. Even now, I tend to expand everything, like the definition of energy, into excruciating detail. That’s the only way I know how to check my own proofs.